# Perl: How is to be interpreted a negation of an array and scalar?

Tags: arrays, perl, scalar

What happens if I do a negation of an array or a scalar? Using the script below I got these results:

```
$x = 0
-------------
$x:   0
!$x:  1

$x = 1
-------------
$x:   1
!$x:  

@x = ()
-------------
@x:   
!@x:  1

@x = qw ( a b )
-------------
@x:   ab
!@x:
```

I suppose that if I do a negation of a non empty array or scalar I will get `''` which means in boolean context `false`. Is this correct?

Is there a way to make it "visible"?

What I wonder why `$x=1;` gives `''` for `!$x`and not `0` since `$x=0` gives `1` for `!$x`.

Also here I suppose that every kind of a TRUE object gives `''` if negated and every kind of FALSE object gives 1 if negated.

Writing all this I got aware that Perl is very consistent. Nevertheless that the "standard" FALSE is `''` (not visible) makes me uncomfortable.

---

Code:

```
my $x = 0;
print "\$x = 0\n-------------\n";
print "\$x:   ",$x,"\n";   # 0
print "!\$x:  ",!$x,"\n\n";  # 1
print "\n";

$x = 1;
print "\$x = 1\n-------------\n";
print "\$x:   ",$x,"\n";   # 1
print "!\$x:  ",!$x,"\n\n";  #    (empty?)


my @x = ();
print "\@x = ()\n-------------\n";
print "\@x:   ",@x,"\n";   # a b
print "!\@x:  ",!@x,"\n\n";  # 

@x = qw ( a b );
print "\@x = qw ( a b )\n-------------\n";
print "\@x:   ",@x,"\n";   # 1
print "!\@x:  ",!@x,"\n";  #    (empty?)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `!` (not) operator puts its argument in scalar context. An array in scalar context returns its size -- how many elements it contains. So in your case, when you do

```
!@x
```

You are essentially doing:

```
!2
```

Which is the empty string, as you mentioned, and not `0`.

It is not invisible, but the method you are using to display it does not show it. You could for example print it with the `Data::Dumper` module:

```
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper !@a;
```

Will print

```
$VAR1 = '';
```

Comment: Re "*Which is the empty string, as you mentioned, and not `0`.*", Incorrect. It is a scalar that contains both the empty string and `0`. Actually, it contains two `0`: as an IV and as an NV. Try `perl -we'my $x = ""; $x + 0;'` and `perl -we'my $x = (!1); $x + 0;'`

Comment: @ikegami I suppose IV and NV means integer value and double value. If I run both codes I get `Argument "" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 1.` and `0`  as result for the first code and `0` without warning for the second code. That means that `''` is a string (which cause the warning) but in the context it is treated as `0` that's why the result is `0`. Why `print !1` does not output `0`? How is it possible that a scalar can contain two values `''` and `0`?

Comment: @giordano, `print` needs a string, so it'll use the string in the scalar. `+ 0` needs a number, so it'll use the number in the scalar.